# Is there a way to generate a GraphQL schema from a protobuf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, graphql, graphql-js

I have a rather large/complex protobuf definition of an API, and I wonder if there's a convenient tool to automatically generate a textual GraphQL schema and its (nested) types from a subset of this protobuf?

I'm using Node.js normally, but I'm open for other languages to generate the schema.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is any update on this? Would love to automate the generation of proto to GraphQL schema.

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to use GoLang, there's a protobuf to GraphQL converter at

https://github.com/opsee/protobuf

> Current gadgets
>   graphql
>
> The graphql gadget will generate a graphql schema for protobuf messages for use with the go-graphql package. It defines extensions for use in files, messages, and fields. See examples for usage -- the files generated by the plugin are flavortown.pb.go and flavortownpb_test.go.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question, as it generates Go code, and not plain textual schema definitions, but thanks anyway.

Comment: link results as `archived`

Answer (score 6):

[Rejoiner](http://rejoiner.io/) will create a uniform GraphQL schema from protobuf sources (such as gRPC microservices).

http://rejoiner.io/

https://github.com/google/rejoiner

Comment: Would you please add some extra explanation about it? We shouldn't rely only on external content, that might change or go offline...

Comment: From the question: "a convenient tool to automatically generate a textual GraphQL schema". Since when does Rejoiner generate a textual GraphQL schema? You can introspect it, sure, but that is far from convenient.

Comment: rejoiner.io domain has expired, but github project is still available.

Answer (score 0):

This project generates graphql schemas from protos: https://github.com/tmc/protoc-gen-graphql

Answer (score 0):

[GraphQL Mesh](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/mesh) support gRPC and Protobufs together with many other protocols.

[Here you can find docs and examples](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/mesh/docs/handlers/grpc)